# How to retrieve record values arbitrary number of records previous?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like this one :

```
data test;
input Quantity Time Duration;
cards;
70 15 21 
85 15 14 
120 30 19 
60 15 0 
60 30 0 
60 30 37 
65 30 5 
30 30 30 
40 15 0
60 30 49 
;
run;
```

If my duration is 0, i want to sum the quantity of the previous line to the current line as well as the time of the previous line to the current one to have something like this :

```
70 15 21 
85 15 14 
120 30 19 
180 45 0 
240 75 0 
60 30 37 
65 30 5 
30 30 30 
70 45 0
60 30 49
```

The problem occurs when there are consecutive lines with duration = 0.

So far, I've tried this :

```
data test; 
set test; 
lag_time = lag(time);
lag_quantity = lag(quantity);
if duration = 0 then do ; 
quantity = quantity + lag_quantity;
time = time + lag_time;
end;
run;
```

Which gives me what I want but only for the first duration = 0.

Does someone have another approach?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I changed the title some, as your question title was misleading to some extent.  I don't love the new title though, so please edit it further to something better if anyone can think of a better way to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data test1; 
set test; 
retain lag_quantity lag_time;
if duration = 0 then do ; 
quantity = quantity + lag_quantity;
time = time + lag_time;
end;
lag_time = time;
lag_quantity = quantity;
run;
```

Comment: You can also try to explain how do you think this code would be helpfull to the OP and how can you say this would answer the problem without explaination?

Comment: @Afzaal : no need Joe did that already, just a small variation. I thought of posting as a comment to Joe's answer but it was unreadable

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want and it is an alternative to using the lag function. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3645882 You should include the explanation of the code for this to be a good answer.  Don't rely on other answers, particularly ones that are (slightly, at least) incorrect, as they will probably be deleted.  Your answer should always stand on its own.